# Is it possible put a custom class into Bundle?

Tags: android, class, android-intent, bundle

In my android project I define a class as 'Settings' which includes global setting values and I will use it in many different activities. So I want to pass this class with using Bundle and I tried as Parcelable but it is not working? Can you tell what the best practice is?

This is my class:

```
public class Setting{
        String set1;
        boolean set2;
        int set3;
    }
```

And this how I tried to do intent bundle to another activity:

```
...
Setting sets = new Setting();
sets.set1 = "test";
sets.set2 = true;
sets.set3 = 1;
...
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("pass_settings", (Parcelable) sets );
```

Comment: "So I want to pass this class with using Bundle" -- if this object represents global settings, perhaps you should not be passing it around, but instead have a singleton instance that you use. "I tried as Parcelable but it is not working?" -- you did not implement `Parcelable` on your `Setting` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the Parcelable interface:

```
public class Setting implements Parcelable {
    String set1;
    boolean set2;
    int set3;

    protected Setting(Parcel in) {
        set1 = in.readString();
        set2 = in.readByte() != 0;
        set3 = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Setting> CREATOR = new Creator<Setting>() {
        @Override
        public Setting createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Setting(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Setting[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Setting[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(set1);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (set2 ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeInt(set3);
    }
}
```

then you can put it in a Bundle:

```
bundle.putParcelable("tag_here", setting);
```

Comment: This is what I really looked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert the whole setting object to json string by passing it to intent from current activity & then restore it back to setting object on receiving activity.

Current Activity:

```
 1. Gson gson = new Gson();
 2. String json = gson.toJson(sets);
```

Note: Pass the json string to intent.

Receiving Activity:
Note: Receive the json string from intent.

```
 1. Gson gson = new Gson();
 2. Setting sets = gson.fromJson(json, Setting.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Paracable

```
public class Settings implements Paracable{

    String set1;
    boolean set2;
    int set3;

   // Parcelling part

 public static final Creator<Setting> CREATOR = new Creator<Setting>() {
        @Override
        public Setting createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Setting(in);
        }

        @Override
    public Setting[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Setting[size];
    }
};
   public Settings (Parcel in){
       this.set1= in.readLong();
       this.set2 = in.readString();
       this.set3 =  in.readString();
   }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
      dest.writeString(this.set1);
      dest.writeBoolean(this.set2);
      dest.writeInt(this.set3);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Settings implements Parcelable {
    private String mSet1;
    private boolean mSet2;
    private int mSet3;

    public Settings(){}

    protected Settings(Parcel in) {
        mSet1 = in.readString();
        mSet2 = in.readByte() != 0;
        mSet3 = in.readInt();
    }

    public String getSet1() {
        return mSet1;
    }

    public void setSet1(final String set1) {
        mSet1 = set1;
    }

    public boolean isSet2() {
        return mSet2;
    }

    public void setSet2(final boolean set2) {
        mSet2 = set2;
    }

    public int getSet3() {
        return mSet3;
    }

    public void setSet3(final int set3) {
        mSet3 = set3;
    }

    public static final Creator<Settings> CREATOR = new Creator<Settings>() {
        @Override
        public Settings createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Settings(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Settings[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Settings[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(final Parcel dest, final int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mSet1);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (mSet2 ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeInt(mSet3);
    }

    private void test(){
        Settings toSave = new Settings();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("bundle_key", toSave);

        Settings settings = bundle.getParcelable("bundle_key`enter code here`"); 
    }
}
```